# Color pallete names lookup for chroma.js

Tags: color

In chroma.js, there are named color palletes or 'scales' such as Viridis, Spectral, RdYlBu (Red, Yellow, Blue), Reds, Greys, etc. I know some of these are based on Color Brewer. However, I do not see a look up table in the docs for these names with their colors. How can I know that such acronym would work such as "RdYlBu"?

Comment: Can you provide some links pls? It is hard to navigate between several GitHub pages to find out what you are referring to.

Comment: Hi here is the library: https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#color-scales